# Bootstrap is loading in html, but bootstrap.css is not visible in Console in Network

Tags: css, linux, firefox, console, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap in a html file. All other files like filename.html, styles.css, bootstrap.bundle.min.js are visible in network tab in console. Using it on linux mint with firefox browser.In Bootstrap docs- [https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/browsers-devices/](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)  , it says -Unofficially, Bootstrap should look and behave well enough in Chromium and Chrome for Linux, and Firefox for Linux, though they are not officially supported.Is this the reason that Even though bootstrap.css is loading in html, it does not show in firefox console in network. What coould be the possible reason for this and will it lead to any performance issues while using bootstrap in linux in firefox. [console-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4B4k.png)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1 class="text-center text-info">Hello, world!</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6"><button class="btn btn-primary"type="button">hello</button></div>
        <div class="col-lg-6"><button class="btn btn-block"type="button">brother</button></div>
   
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

tried hiding styles.css, changing positions of href and link , searched for probable answers on net

Comment: I assume the browser is caching the file for improved performance purposes.

Comment: I tried clearing cache, but it did not change. I checked this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qfEOE4vtxE , where it says at 8:58 mins,  that on bootstrap css and js loading , it will be visible in console network. Later i checked in windows firefox, it is the same. On chrome, it is altogether different. Dont know whether it is an aberration or a norm . Just knowing whether it is one of the point one should consider for successful loading of bootstrap css and js.

Comment: Nope it's just a Firefox thing.  On my Mac, I get the same behavior where I don't see the CSS file in the Network tab unless I specifically click the "disable cache" checkbox.